# Outstanding allegories/definitions of body and life

Tags: meaning-of-life

The most famous definition of the human body is Plato's soma-sema, a prison, a tomb, a burden, then an archetype of perfection, a tool by which to reach balance: many are the allegories used by philosophers and poets for life: a dream, an illusion, vanity, a disease, atonement or exile, a tale meaning nothing, a business whose returns are far from covering the cost, a chance to reach redemption.

Can you add anything of interest to this list?

Comment: Sounds oddly like homework.

Comment: @BillOnne, ha ha!